# How can I set the version of a raw file in a (Sonatype) Nexus raw repository?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I'm making an automatic script to upload a raw file in Nexus, and I need to set up the version of this file. Is this possible? I've been checking the API but it doesn't seem posible.

The command I'm currently using to upload is:

```
curl --proxy $my-proxy -v --user 'user:pass' --upload-file ./myRawFile 'http://12.34.56.78:1234/repository/MyRawRepo/LoL/TheUploadedFile'
```

This command is being used from an automatic script (and working) to upload the file, but I don't know how to set the version.

Comment: There is no versioning in the raw repository.  I can add an answer with that if you like, however, my source is working with the tool; I don't think the documentation states this, so not sure if that's enough for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
curl -k -u "xxx:xxx" -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --data-binary "@output.zip" -X PUT https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/{raw-reponame}/xxx/{version}/output.zip
```

Version number can be change **{version}**